# htaccess Rewrite Rule - Allowing Capital Letters in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^brand/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ find_by_brand.php?brand=$1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} find_by_brand\.php
RewriteRule ^find_by_brand\.php - [F]
```

I want it to be able to work if I go to **/Michelin/** and also **/michelin/**

Does anyone have any idea what I could add to make that work?

Thanks!

Comment: But `a-zA-Z` already will match you that part regardless of the case ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `[NC]` flag ("no case")

```
RewriteRule ^brand/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ find_by_brand.php?brand=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Perfect thanks.  Quick question.. if I am adding another RewriteRule for the index, I have: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?shop_id=$1 [L,QSA]   - It is messing with my first rewrite rule posted above.  Am I allowed to have more than one?

Comment: @Drew also add the `[L]` flag to this one to prevent it from interfering with the next one.  Edited above.